# When a open set is the union of countable compact sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

$\Omega$ is open in a topological space $X$ and $\{K_n\}$ are countable open sets such that $\bigcup K_n = \Omega$ and $K_n \subset \text{int} K_{n+1}$.

Suppose there is another compact set $K \subset \Omega$. Then, is there a $K_N \in  \{K_n\}$ such that $K \subset K_N$?

If it doesn't hold generally, then does it hold when $X$ is a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what is $K_N$ ?

Comment: $K_N$  is one of $K_n$'s.

Comment: Usually the $K_n$ are assumed to be compact, or have compact closures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always true. The interiors if the sets $K_n$ form an open cover if $K$ and there is a finite subcover. But any finite Union is contained on one of the sets $K_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really clear.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the space is nice enough like $\mathbb{R}^n$, suppose it is not true, for every integer $n$, there exists $x_n$ in $K$ and not  in $K_n$, the sequence $x_n$ has a subsequence which converges towards $x\in K,$ so $x\in K_{n_0}\subset int(K_{n_0+1})$ this implies that there exists $N_0$ such that for every $n>N_0, x_n\in int(K_{n_0+1})$ contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your help!